# querying user's photos in parse

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I'm making an app that has users and each user has their own photos and profile page. I want the profile page to display only the photos for the user. Here is my code so far:

```
    var query = PFUser.query()!
    query.limit = 300
    query.whereKey("User", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (caption: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // on a réussi

            for caption in caption! {
                self.photosforfeed.append(caption["fichierimage"] as! PFFile)


            } // end for loop

            println(self.photosforfeed.count)
            self.usernamelabel.text = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
            self.totalphotoscountlabel.text = self.photosforfeed.count.description
            self.collectionview.reloadData()
        } // end if error == nil
        else {
            println("es gab etwas nicht gut")
        }
    }
```

any idea what is wrong? I searched in the parse iOS docs but this still isn't working. thanks

by "not working" I mean that the view on the view controller does not show anything. Nothing is displayed. the log/consolt displays nothing as well.

Comment: You need to be more specific, what is not working? what your logs show? what your table look like? We can't really help much without more details

Comment: What do you think `caption` Array contains?